# How can I ask a good Strategy/tactics question?

Tags: discussion, questions

Say [I want to beat a boss](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52680/how-can-i-beat-the-true-final-boss-of-hitogata-happa). I ask here; it's the first on-topic category in the [faq](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq). But strategy questions are inherently a bit subjective.

How can I ask these sort of questions so they are a good fit for Gaming.SE? Do I just say "here's what I want to do, here's what I've done"?

Comment: Why not do exactly that?

Comment: @badp that's exactly what I did, I'm just wondering if we're picky about them or what. They're more subjective/loosely defined than most SE sites would allow yet they're a vital part of the site in our case.

Answer (score 9):

[Strategy and Tactics are pretty much the pinnacle of good subjective.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

They're about How, and a well written answer will explain Why. They tend to attract long answers, with lots of detail. They're constructive, because you're asking about how to *accomplish a task*, not simply whether a particular activity is enjoyable.

There's nothing wrong with them, and they are, fundamentally, our bread and butter.

Answer (score 5):

Answers to strategy questions *are* inherently subjective - "this worked for me" or "this is how I think it can be done". Still, not all subjective questions are automatically frowned upon in this site; you can read more about it in [this stack exchange blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

In general strategy questions such as "how do I beat this boss" are welcome here. Just ask away, but do try to include details in your question - e.g. what have you tried, what is your specific difficulty, etc.