# Is a question about strategies valid?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I ask a good Strategy/tactics question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4089/how-can-i-ask-a-good-strategy-tactics-question)

So I'm keen to ask a question about XCOM and the use of Heavy units as I've struggled all campaign to use them effectively, other than the rocket/blaster launcher. I tend to find that even if I'm 3-4 squares away from a target in half-cover I get a hit chance of around 25%.

I want to ask a question about the effective use of Heavy units in XCOM. However I feel that this would spark discussion due to the fact that the game is about tactics and strategy and different people would employ the heavies differently.

On the other hand, I do think that there must be a 'best-case' scenario for the use of this unit as having googled I am not alone in struggling to find a way to effectivly use a heavy.

Is this a valid question, or would it need to be phrased in a way to give a more difinitive answer by reducing the variables involed? Such as defining my use-case.

> Taking into account that my Colonel level Heavy uses the right-hand perk tree (Holo-targeting etc), is equipped with Heavy Plasma and Plasma Blaster, has Ghost Armour and Scope (upgraded); what would be the most effective strategy for the use of this unit?

*Aside*
Just wanted to put in a short paragraph to justify why I think this is a valid question.

Gaming stackexchange is an FAQ, which to me is a little bit of a shame just because of the sheer volume of expertise on offer, but I do feel that questions like this are valid, because the system allows for discussion with the question asker being able to select the most appropriate answer to solve that discussion in their eyes. Sometimes I feel the site panders too much to Google and not enough to the actual question asker. Allowing more discussion would nurture more community. Which is why I think this question is valid.

**PS**
I should mention that a valid answer could be found by distilling the wikia entry. http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Heavy_Class

Comment: If questions about strategy weren't valid, we probably wouldn't be able to exist.

Comment: Strategy questions are fine, as long as they're not entirely open ended, e.g., "How do I win?" Better: "How can I win combats on Impossible?" / "What are strategies for base building?" etc.

Comment: Nice condescending answer @LessPop_MoreFizz. Looks like there is no winning with Arqade. :_(

Comment: You epitomise my point exactly @StrixVaria

Comment: I can't say that I see the condescension in LessPop's statement. It's a valid point. It also isn't clear to me what point Strix is epitomising.

Comment: LessPop isn't being condescending.  The point is that strategy questions are valid on this site and you should feel free to ask yours.

Comment: @JasonBerkan That would have been a better thing to have said, especially as it would have actually answered my question. Instead I got some snarky comment and the question gets closed, even on meta!. It's just the way that Arqade feels to me. People would rather close your question than answer it, even if they know the answer. It doesn't really help people, if anything I think it drives away users from the site. I know I hold a minority opinion, but it's just how the site is for me. At least I took the time to ask if my question was valid, and it still got closed!

Comment: @David Raven said "Strategy questions are fine".  That was your answer.  Linking to the duplicate question was just a way for you to get more detailed discussion.  Closing the question isn't a black mark against you, it just tells people to look elsewhere for the discussion rather than repeating it here.

Comment: Crap, [I'm arguing on the Internet. I should go make a sandwich.](http://www.systemcomic.com/2011/08/03/so-youre-mad-about-something-on-the-internet/)

Comment: And then after your sandwich, ask your question.  I'm already composing an answer... (tl;dr - Heavy's need to be positioned properly, since they benefit the most from not having to move as their first action.)